# Toolbar: remove view does not remove child

Tags: android

I do:

```
getActionBarToolbar().removeView(logoImage);
getActionBarToolbar().addView(logoImage, lp);
```

I get:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

BTW:

```
((ViewGroup) logoImage.getParent()).removeView(logoImage) does not help.
```

Any ideas what's  wrong?

Comment: when do you call this method? also, use removeViewAt(int) or try removeViewInLayout(View view); im implementing knowledge based on viewgroups..okay.. where and when do you call your method?????

Comment: @Elltz I call it in activity running state.

Comment: call it in onResume..

Comment: @Elltz why should I do it in onResume? 
I need to do it when my activity in running state. I remove and add things dynamically in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not actually solved it (maybe it is a bug) but for my purpose was enough to change visibility of the logoImage.
'logoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE)'